# Pgfplots with custom axis markers

Tags: pgfplots

Assume you have a trigonometric function, say for simplicity `sin(x)`. When plotting the function, how can one place the x-axis markers on 0, pi/2, pi, 3pi/2, 2pi, instead of the default numeric values that `pgfplots` uses?

Comment: Related question: [axis with trigonometric labels in pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34939/axis-with-trigonometric-labels-in-pgfplots)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use `\xtick` to specify where you want the ticks, and `\xticklabels` to specify the corresponding labels.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line=center, 
    axis y line=middle, 
    xtick={0,1.5708,3.14159,4.7123889},
    xticklabels={$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,$\pi$,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$},
    domain=0:2*pi
]
\addplot {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you don't want a label a particular tick mark, just leave that one blank. For example, if you did not want the label at pi you would replace the line with `xticklabels={$0$,$\frac{\pi}{2}$,,$\frac{3\pi}{2}$}`.

Comment: This code puts the labels at the wrong places.

Comment: @celil: Can you clarify what you mean. The location looks correct to me. I see that you asked for one at 2pi, so do you mean that the above example is missing that? If so, you can just add one more label.

Comment: I take my comment back. For some reason when I compiled before, the x-axis ticks did not correspond to the correct positions, but now the ticks are at the correct positions.

Comment: Am i wrong or the thick mark at 0 does not show up?

Comment: @mmj: Hmmm... Appears as if you are correct. Perhaps you should post a follow up question.

Comment: It seems the problems has already be addressed: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78763/28685 . In your MWE `axis y line=left` should replace `axis y line=middle`.

Comment: @mmj: Thanks for finding that.  If this question gets edited, I'll add that link to the answer.

Comment: I have a question regarding the use of pi as a number in this example. In the `\xtick` command you used 3.14, but in the `\domain` command you seem to use pi as a numeric value. How can I use pi generally as numeric value?

Comment: @Christine: Looks like `xtick` require a numerical value, but the parser for the `domain` seems to allow one to use `pi`. Might be good to post a good follow-up qustion.

Answer (score 7):

You can specify the position of the ticks using the `xtick` and `scaled x ticks` options. Example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xtick={0,1.5708,...,10},domain=0:2*pi,scaled x ticks={real:3.1415},
  xtick scale label code/.code={$\cdot \pi$}]
\addplot {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Taken from page 183 of the manual.

Answer (score 6):

Using `gnuplot`, I suggest the following:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
% GNUPLOT required
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:6.3]
    \foreach \x/\xtext in {0/0, 0.5*pi/\frac{\pi}{2} ,pi/\pi,
      1.5*pi/\frac{3\pi}{2}, 2*pi/2\pi}
    \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$\xtext$};
    \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (2*pi,1.1); 
    \draw[color=blue] plot[id=sin] function{sin(x)} node[right] {$f(x) = \sin x$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Which is maybe simpler. Maybe not... I'm using explicit representation of the axis' labels.
[image: The result]