# Axis with trigonometric labels in PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots

How do I make the axis labels use multiples of `\pi` in PGFPlots?
[image]

Comment: See the example in `pgfplots` manual pages 262-263 (manual for version 1.5, of July 29 2011) for a solution. (Assuming you're after the labels on the `x`-axis.)

Comment: I think you mean "display one axis".  If so, which one? Can you clarify the question a bit?  Also, it would help to show the code that produced your figure, not just the figure.

Comment: Does [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23461/pgfplots-with-custom-axis-markers) help?

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for. Please compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Did you look at [Pgfplots with custom axis markers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23461/1952)? I think they solve your question. May be not an automatic solution, but a solution which looks like the one at page 264-265 (section 4.21) of pgfplots manual.

Comment: I have added a feature request for for an automatic solution: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/feature-requests/42/

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is basically the same as [Pgfplots with custom axis markers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23461/pgfplots-with-custom-axis-markers). All you need to do is to specify where you want the `xtick={...}` and how you want each of them labelled via `xticklabels={...}`.

### Method 1: Explicit Labels:

Explicit labels can be specified using `xticklabels`.
The one complication that comes about is that sometimes the label overlaps with the plot as is the case for `-\pi` and `2pi` in the blue graph. I have not found a elegant way to fix that so I just manually add some spacing to those labels to tweak them as I did the red graph:

[image]

### Method 2: Scaled Axis Labels:

An alternate is to scale the x-axis labels in terms of multiples of `pi`, and show that the x axis labels are multiples of `pi`.  This solution is based on [Spikes solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23461/pgfplots-with-custom-axis-markers/23462#23462), so you should up vote that if you prefer this version.  I prefer to label this as part of the axis (brown graph), but others might prefer to display it as in the cyan graph:

[image]

### `xticklabels`:

If you want a tick mark, but not a corresponding label you can simply place an empty label as in `$$` or just better just use a double comma `,,` to skip it being labelled. For instance, if the labels at `+\pi` and `-\pi` are not desired, simply replace those labels with spaces (extra spaces here are just to point out where the gap is):

```
xticklabels={$-2\pi$, $-\frac{3\pi}{2}$,    , $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, 
             $\frac{\pi}{2}$,     , $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $2\pi$}
```

### `xtick`:

Note that two methods of specifying where the tick marks go are used in the code.  One is to explicitly list them as

```
xtick={-6.28318, -4.7123889, -3.14159, -1.5708, 1.5708, 3.14159, 4.7123889, 6.28318}
```

This is used in the first two examples so that the correspondence between the `xtick` and `xticklabels` is easier to see.  The second two use the more compact method:

```
xtick={-6.28318, -4.7123889, ..., 6.28318}
```

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Grouping the common style settings here to make the code below easier to read
\pgfkeys{/pgfplots/Axis Style/.style={
    width=13.5cm, height=5cm,
    axis x line=center, 
    axis y line=middle, 
    samples=100,
    ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
    xmin=-7.0, xmax=7.0,
    domain=-2*pi:2*pi
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    Axis Style,
    xtick={
        -6.28318, -4.7123889, -3.14159, -1.5708,
        1.5708, 3.14159, 4.7123889, 6.28318
    },
    xticklabels={
        $-2\pi$, $-\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $-\pi$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$,
        $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $2\pi$
    }
]
\addplot [mark=none, ultra thick, blue] {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    Axis Style,
    xtick={
        -6.28318, -4.7123889, -3.14159, -1.5708,
        1.5708, 3.14159, 4.7123889, 6.28318
    },
    xticklabels={
        $-2\pi$, $-\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $-\pi\hspace{0.30cm}$, $-\frac{\pi}{2}$,
        $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\pi\hspace{0.10cm}$, $\frac{3\pi}{2}$, $\hspace{0.25cm} 2\pi$
    }
]
\addplot [mark=none, ultra thick, red] {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    Axis Style,
    xtick={-6.28318, -4.7123889, ..., 6.28318},
    scaled x ticks={real:3.1415},
    xtick scale label code/.code={},
    xlabel={$x \thinspace [\times \pi]$}
]
\addplot [mark=none, ultra thick, brown] {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    Axis Style,
    xtick={-6.28318, -4.7123889, ..., 6.28318},
    scaled x ticks={real:3.1415},
    xtick scale label code/.code={$[\times \pi]$},
    xlabel={$x$}
]
\addplot [mark=none, ultra thick, cyan] {sin(deg(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Is there a way to specify `xtick` using a `\foreach` loop? This would be useful if one wanted to have different fractions of `\pi`.

Comment: @cmhughes: I had attempted something similar and  manually add the tick labels but have not come up with an elegant solution. See my related posts: [Using macro defined lists in tikz pgfplot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17833/using-macro-defined-lists-in-tikz-pgfplots), and [PGFplots foreach equivalent to TikZ's with multiple variables separated by a slash](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/pgfplots-foreach-equivalent-to-tikzs-with-multiple-variables-separated-by-a-sla).

Comment: @cmhughes: Also related: [Macro to access a specific member of a list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21559/macro-to-access-a-specific-member-of-a-list)

Comment: @cmhughes: See alternate solution which does not require you to specify each point explicitly.

Answer (score 15):

There is also a bit more "automated" solution which I first presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291424/95441) (-- this seems to be a duplicate of this question --) with some more refinement inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100701/95441) answer.

Please have a look at the comments of the code to find out, how it works.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        axis lines=middle,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,
        no markers,
        samples=51,
        trig format plots=rad,
        %
        % create a style to scale x axis values by \pi and
        % remove the corresponding label
        x axis in pi/.style={
            scaled x ticks={real:\PI},
            xtick scale label code/.code={},
            % in case you want to set an explicit tick distance
            xtick distance=pi/#1,
            % add code here for formatting the `xticklabels'
            % I configured exceptions for \pm\pi where no number in front
            % of these are shown and for fractional values these should be
            % shown as fractions
            xticklabel={%
                % to avoid some mess with TeX precision, first
                % round the `\tick' value to one digit after the comma
                \pgfmathparse{round(100*\tick)/100}
                \ifdim \pgfmathresult pt = 1pt
                    \strut$\pi$%
                \else\ifdim \pgfmathresult pt = -1pt
                    \strut$-\pi$%
                \else
                    % depending on whether the resulting number is an integer
                    % show it as integer only, otherwise use the style given
                    % in `xticklabel style'
                    \pgfmathifisint{\pgfmathresult}{%
                        \strut$\pgfmathprintnumber[int detect]{\pgfmathresult}\pi$%
                    }{%
                        % show \pi next to the frac
                        \strut$\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\pi$%
%                        % show \pi in the numerator of the frac
%                        \pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult*#1}%
%                        \strut$\frac{\pgfmathprintnumber[int detect]{\pgfmathresult}\pi}{#1}$%
                    }
                \fi\fi
            },
            % set number plotting to frac style
            xticklabel style={
                /pgf/number format/.cd,
                    frac,
                    frac whole=false,
%                    % if you prefer to have the same denominator value everywhere
%                    frac denom=#1,
            },
        },
    }
    % define precision of \pi
    % this is set here to the value of \pgfmathpi
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\PI}{pi}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
%            % uncomment the next two lines for `x axis in pi=4' so the
%            % `xticklabels' don't overlap
%            width=1.5*\axisdefaultwidth,
%            height=\axisdefaultheight,
            domain=-1.1*pi:2.1*pi,
            ymin=-1.1,
            ymax=+1.1,
            % apply the above created style
            % (works for the values 1, 2 and 4)
            x axis in pi=2,
            ytick distance=1,
            smooth,
        ]
            \addplot {sin(x)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Is it possible to encapsulate your code to a key/style?

Comment: Is it also possible to have $\frac{\pi}{2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{2}\pi$ etc.?

Comment: If I change $\PI/2$ to $\PI/4$ in your code it doesn't work anymore (gives large fractions), changing 10 to 1000 in round, and loading fp solves this, but I didn't manage to make $\PI/8$ work...

Comment: @Julia, of course you can encapsulate it into a style and you also can place `\pi` in the numerator of `\frac`. Therefore see my edited code. Unfortunately I am also unable to make my solution work for `\pi/8`, sorry.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another solution inspired by Stefan Pinnow's answer. To avoid the precision issue with `/pgf/number format/frac`, it calculates explicitly the reduced fraction for every label, so it should work for pi/8, etc.

[image: sin(x)]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

% Workaround for gcd() issue in pgfplots 1.14
% (see https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/129/ and
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328972/ )
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\let\pgfmathgcdX=\pgfmathgcd@
\usepackage{pgfplots}%
\let\pgfmathgcd@=\pgfmathgcdX
\makeatother

% Load math library, for \tikzmath
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\pgfplotsset{
    % Typeset fractions of pi at regular intervals on x axis
    x axis in pi/.style={
        % Make sure the x axis is in radians
        trig format plots=rad,
        % Set tick distance from style argument
        xtick distance={pi/#1},
        % Set label style: calculate reduced fraction of pi
        xticklabel={
            \tikzmath{
                % Calculate this tick's multiple of pi/#1
                int \numorig, \gcd, \num, \denom, \absnum;
                \numorig = round(\tick*#1/pi);
                % Calculate reduced fraction for \numorig/#1
                \gcd = gcd(\numorig,#1);
                \num = \numorig / \gcd;
                \absnum = abs(\num);
                \denom = #1 / \gcd;
                % Build label text
                if \num < 0 then {
                    let \sign = -;
                } else {
                    let \sign =;
                };
                if \absnum == 1 then {
                    let \numpi = \pi;
                } else {
                    let \numpi = \absnum\pi;
                };
                if \denom == 1 then {
                    if \num == 0 then {
                        { \strut$0$ };
                    } else {
                        { \strut$\sign\numpi$ };
                    };
                } else {
                    { \strut$\sign\frac{\numpi}{\denom}$ };
                    % Other style with all pi symbols same and aligned:
                    %{ \strut$\sign\frac{\absnum}{\denom}\pi$ };
                };
            }
        },
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=14cm,
        axis equal image,
        domain=-2*pi:2*pi,
        axis lines=center,
        enlargelimits={abs=0.4},
        no markers,
        samples=100,
        ytick distance = 1,
        x axis in pi=2, % tick distance as fraction of pi
        ]
        \addplot {sin(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The workaround for `gcd()` issue isn't needed anymore (at least in `pgfplots` 1.18).

Comment: Note that this code currently (`pgfplots` 1.18) doesn't work with the beamer class. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/688609/18401.

Answer (score 1):

I realize the question is on PGFPlots, but I was interested in finding or providing in this case a solution using only TikZ code. Although the PGFPlots automation and mathematical nature of the code is appealing, I wonder if all the overhead is necessary for most Trig graphs. In any case, here is my solution. The one concern I had in making this graph was for the axes to represent true relative distances. Therefore, the x-axis is scaled by pi/4 while the y-axis is simply units of natural numbers.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}    \usepackage{amsfonts}   \usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}     \usepackage{latexsym}   \usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,calc}

\begin{document}


\newcommand*{\xMin}{-9}
\newcommand*{\xMax}{9}
\newcommand*{\yMin}{-3}
\newcommand*{\yMax}{3}
\scriptsize
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth,scale=0.65]

        \foreach \i in {\xMin,...,\xMax} {
        \draw [-,very thin,gray,scale={pi/4}] (\i,{-3/(pi/4)}) -- (\i,{3/(pi/4)});
        }

        \foreach \i in {\yMin,...,\yMax} {
        \draw [-,very thin,gray] ({\xMin*pi/4},\i) -- ({\xMax*pi/4},\i);
        }

        \draw node at ({pi},0) [below] {${\pi}$};
        \draw node at ({2*pi},0) [below] [xshift=1pt] {${2\pi}$};
        \draw node at ({-pi},0) [below] [xshift=-2pt]  {${-\pi}$};
        \draw node at ({-2*pi},0) [below] [xshift=-2pt] {${-2\pi}$};

        \draw node at (0,1) [left] {$1$};
        \draw node at (0,2) [left] {$2$};
        \draw node at (0,-1) [left] {$-1$};
        \draw node at (0,-2) [left] {$-2$};


        \draw [->] [thick] ({\xMin*(pi/4)},0) -- ({\xMax*(pi/4)+0.5},0) 
            node [right] {$x$};
        \draw [->] [thick] (0,-3) -- (0,3.5)
            node [pos=0.45] [xshift=-3.5pt,yshift=-2pt] {$o$}
            node [above] {$y$};

        \draw [-,thick,magenta,domain={-2*pi}:{2*pi},samples=100] 
        plot (\x, {sin(\x*180/pi)});

        \end{tikzpicture}
\normalsize


\end{document}
```

[image: sine waves]

Comment: No fractional labels?