# unit circle sin(x) radians on x-axe

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Adapting the code from another question, but still having one problem:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{angle}
\setcounter{angle}{220}


\begin{tikzpicture}

% Axis
\draw[thick,-stealth,black] (-3,0)--(4,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$x$}; % x axis
\draw[thick,-stealth,black] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[left] {$y$}; % y axis
\draw[black,thin] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
\node[black,below] at (2.7,0) {1};
\node[black,above] at (0.2,-3.2) {1};

%\draw[ultra thick,orange] (0,0) -- (\theangle:2.5cm |- 0,0) node[midway,below] {$\cos \alpha$}; % UpOn y axis

\draw (1,0) arc (0:\theangle:1) node at ($(\theangle/2:0.7)$) {$\alpha$};
\draw[dashed, cyan] (\theangle:2.5cm) -- (\theangle:2.5cm |- 0,0) node[sloped, rotate=180, yshift=8pt, midway] {$\sin \alpha$}; % vertical line
\draw[ultra thick,red,rotate=\theangle] (0,0) -- (2.5,0) coordinate (B); 
\foreach \x in {0,30,...,360} {\filldraw[black] (\x:2.5cm) circle(1pt);};
\foreach \x/\xtext in {
        30/\frac{\pi}{6},
        60/\frac{\pi}{3},
        120/\frac{2\pi}{3},
        150/\frac{5\pi}{6},
        210/\frac{7\pi}{6},
        240/\frac{4\pi}{3},
        300/\frac{5\pi}{3},
        330/\frac{11\pi}{6}
        }
    \draw (\x:2.8cm) node {\tiny $\xtext$};
 \foreach \x/\xtext in {
        90/\frac{\pi}{2}}
        \draw (\x:2.7cm) node[xshift=4pt] {\tiny $\xtext$};    
 \foreach \x/\xtext in {
        270/\frac{3\pi}{2}}
        \draw (\x:2.7cm) node[xshift=-5pt] {\tiny $\xtext$};  
 \foreach \x/\xtext in {
        180/\pi,
        360/2\pi}
        \draw (\x:2.7cm) node[yshift=4pt] {\tiny $\xtext$};             

\begin{scope}
\begin{axis}[
    thick,
    y=2.5cm,
    axis lines=center,
    xmin=0, xmax=360,
    ymin=-1, ymax=1,
    anchor=origin, at=(A),
    xshift=3ex,
    enlarge y limits,
    enlarge x limits=upper,
    samples=90,
    xtick={0,30,...,360},
    tick label style={font=\tiny},
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0:\theangle,ultra thick, no markers,cyan] {sin(x)} coordinate (C);
    \addplot[domain=\theangle-1:\theangle,ultra thick, no markers,cyan] {sin(x)-sin(x)} coordinate (K);

\end{axis}
\draw [dashed,red, thick] (B) -- (C);
\draw [dashed,cyan, thick] (C) -- (K);
\end{scope}

\tkzDrawPoints(B);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I make the x-axe having the angles in radians, as displayed on the unit circle.

[image: sinus and unit circle]

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34958/43442) on a similar question might help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
xticklabels={0,
    $\frac{\pi}{6}$,
    $\frac{\pi}{3}$,
    $\frac{\pi}{2}$,        
    $\frac{2\pi}{3}$,
    $\frac{5\pi}{6}$,
    $\pi$,
    $\frac{7\pi}{6}$,
    $\frac{4\pi}{3}$,
    $\frac{3\pi}{2}$,        
    $\frac{5\pi}{3}$,
    $\frac{11\pi}{6}$,
    $2\pi$
    },
```

to the `axis` options.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\newcounter{angle}
\setcounter{angle}{220}


\begin{tikzpicture}

% Axis
\draw[thick,-stealth,black] (-3,0)--(4,0) coordinate (A) node[below] {$x$}; % x axis
\draw[thick,-stealth,black] (0,-3)--(0,3) node[left] {$y$}; % y axis
\draw[black,thin] (0,0) circle (2.5cm);
\node[black,below] at (2.7,0) {1};
\node[black,above] at (0.2,-3.2) {1};

%\draw[ultra thick,orange] (0,0) -- (\theangle:2.5cm |- 0,0) node[midway,below] {$\cos \alpha$}; % UpOn y axis

\draw (1,0) arc (0:\theangle:1) node at ($(\theangle/2:0.7)$) {$\alpha$};
\draw[dashed, cyan] (\theangle:2.5cm) -- (\theangle:2.5cm |- 0,0) node[sloped, rotate=180, yshift=8pt, midway] {$\sin \alpha$}; % vertical line
\draw[ultra thick,red,rotate=\theangle] (0,0) -- (2.5,0) coordinate (B); 
\foreach \x in {0,30,...,360} {\filldraw[black] (\x:2.5cm) circle(1pt);};
\foreach \x/\xtext in {
        30/\frac{\pi}{6},
        60/\frac{\pi}{3},
        120/\frac{2\pi}{3},
        150/\frac{5\pi}{6},
        210/\frac{7\pi}{6},
        240/\frac{4\pi}{3},
        300/\frac{5\pi}{3},
        330/\frac{11\pi}{6}
        }
    \draw (\x:2.8cm) node {\tiny $\xtext$};
 \foreach \x/\xtext in {
        90/\frac{\pi}{2}}
        \draw (\x:2.7cm) node[xshift=4pt] {\tiny $\xtext$};    
 \foreach \x/\xtext in {
        270/\frac{3\pi}{2}}
        \draw (\x:2.7cm) node[xshift=-5pt] {\tiny $\xtext$};  
 \foreach \x/\xtext in {
        180/\pi,
        360/2\pi}
        \draw (\x:2.7cm) node[yshift=4pt] {\tiny $\xtext$};             

\begin{scope}
\begin{axis}[
    thick,
    y=2.5cm,
    axis lines=center,
    xmin=0, xmax=360,
    ymin=-1, ymax=1,
    anchor=origin, at=(A),
    xshift=3ex,
    enlarge y limits,
    enlarge x limits=upper,
    samples=90,
    xtick={0,30,...,360},
xticklabels={0,
    $\frac{\pi}{6}$,
    $\frac{\pi}{3}$,
    $\frac{\pi}{2}$,        
    $\frac{2\pi}{3}$,
    $\frac{5\pi}{6}$,
    $\pi$,
    $\frac{7\pi}{6}$,
    $\frac{4\pi}{3}$,
    $\frac{3\pi}{2}$,        
    $\frac{5\pi}{3}$,
    $\frac{11\pi}{6}$,
    $2\pi$
    },
    tick label style={font=\tiny},
    ]
    \addplot[domain=0:\theangle,ultra thick, no markers,cyan] {sin(x)} coordinate (C);
    \addplot[domain=\theangle-1:\theangle,ultra thick, no markers,cyan] {sin(x)-sin(x)} coordinate (K);

\end{axis}
\draw [dashed,red, thick] (B) -- (C);
\draw [dashed,cyan, thick] (C) -- (K);
\end{scope}

\tkzDrawPoints(B);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```