# Use pi in x labels with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, foreach

With

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[samples=10, domain=0:pi]
\addplot {x-sin(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I get a plot and an x axis from 0 to pi and labels 0, 1, 2, and 3.

What is the best way to get labels with pi instead of whole numbers on the axis?

Comment: See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34939/axis-with-trigonometric-labels-in-pgfplots)