# How to draw in tikz with label in radians

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels

I want to draw in TikZ the graph of the next image:

[image]

Comment: You could try to adapt what is in [Axis with trigonometric labels in PGFPlots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34939/axis-with-trigonometric-labels-in-pgfplots). If that does not work, please make an attempt and compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem showing what you attempted and what you had difficulty with.

Comment: I would just draw the figure with the "real" distances, write by hand the labels, and then scale the whole to the desired size.

Comment: What are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, considering the amount of extra code besides the plot, I personally think using Tikz would be more appropriate in this case, the code is easier. Although it would be doable with `pgfplots` as well.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\Large]
\draw[{Stealth}-{Stealth}] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[{Stealth}-{Stealth}, name path=xaxis] (-2.5,0) -- (10,0) node[right] {$x$};

\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \ylab using int(\y/2)] in {-4,-2,2,4}{%
    \node[anchor=east] at (0,\y) {\ylab};
    \draw (0,\y) --++ (2mm,0);
}

\foreach \x in {1,...,9}{%
    \draw (\x,0) --++ (0,2mm);
}

\draw[thick, loosely dotted, shorten <= 2.5mm, shorten >= 2mm] (3,0) -- (3,4) node[midway, fill=white] {$A=2$} -- (0,4);
\draw (1,0) -- (1,-5);
\draw (9,0) -- (9,-5);
\draw (1,-4.5) -- (9,-4.5) 
    node[pos=.35, fill=white, font=\Large] {$T=\dfrac{9\pi}{4}-\dfrac{\pi}{4}=2\pi$};

\draw[domain=-0.01:8.01, name path=plot, samples=150, very thick] plot (\x+1,{sin(deg(\x*pi/4))*4});

\node (frc) at (3.5,-2.5) {$\phi=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$};
\draw[-{Stealth}, shorten >=3mm] (frc) -- (1,0);

\foreach \xl/\anchor [count=\xx] in {
    1/north east,
    3/north,
    5/north east,
    7/north,
    9/north west}{%
    \path[name path={line\xl}] (\xl,-5) -- (\xl,5);
    \fill[red,name intersections={of={line\xl} and plot,total=\t}]
    \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{(intersection-\s) circle (4pt)};
    %
    \ifnum\xl=1
        \node[anchor=\anchor] at (\xl,0) {$\frac{\vphantom{\xl}\pi}{4}$};
    \else
        \node[anchor=\anchor] at (\xl,0) {$\frac{\xl\pi}{4}$};
    \fi
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Animation time!**

[image]

Comment: Also: while I may understand that you have recently started using Tikz, it's always appreciate from answerers that you can at least get the diagram/image started by drawing the easiest parts of it. For example, while the plot is not easy to figure out (even for more advanced users), the rest of this diagram could have been achieved consulting the manual: axis lines, ticks, etc.

Comment: thanks... one question more, how i do the  animation time?

Comment: @casio enclose the whole `tikzpicture` in a foreach and then use the variable from the foreach in the plot. That should create one "page" per frame in the output.

Comment: I'm starting to use TikZ , I think you could give an example of how it's done , so I analyze and learn

Comment: @casio It's really simple: 1) you should install `imageMagick`, 2) enclose the whole `tikzpicture` with for example: `\foreach \mshift in {1,1,1,1,1.5,...,8.5}{% <tikzpicture here> }`, 3) modify the plot like this: `(\x+\mshift,{sin(deg(\x*pi/4))*4})`, 4) run this from your Terminal/Prompt (you should move to the directory where the PDF is located): `convert -delay 10 -loop 0 -density 300 -scale 400 -alpha remove <file>.pdf <file>.gif`

Comment: Very useful code! I like the `\foreach \xl/\anchor` approach.

Answer (score 1):

Another one with the `pgfplots` machinery (missing the arrow and the period),

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel=$y$,xlabel=$x$,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=0,xmax = 8,ymin=-3,ymax=3,
minor x tick num = 1,
xtick={0.785,2.356,...,7.069},%some multiples of pi with the last one nudged a bit to the left
domain=pi/4:9*pi/4,
xticklabel={$\frac{\ifnum\ticknum>0\relax\number\numexpr2*\ticknum+1\relax\fi\pi}{4}$},
ytick={-2,-1,1,2}
]
\addplot[mark=*,mark options={red},mark repeat=25,samples=101] {2*sin(deg(x)-45)};
\draw[dotted] ({3*pi/4},0) |- (0,2);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]