# How can the effects of \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true} be reversed?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, pgfmath, fpu

Consider the following MNWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro\myresult{Mod(-100,30)}
\tikz{\node {\myresult};}
\end{document}
```

which fails with the following error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, the operation 'Mod' has not yet been implement
ed in the floating point unit :-( (in 'Mod(-100,30)').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.119 \pgfmathsetmacro\myresult{Mod(-100,30)}

?
```

In contrast,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro\myresult{Mod(-100,30)}
\tikz{\node {\myresult};}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
\endgroup
\pgfmathsetmacro\myresult{Mod(-100,30)}
\tikz{\node {\myresult};}
\end{document}
```

work as expected.

However, it seems that it is not always easy to avoid activating the FPU globally.

While you might hope that package authors would take care to limit the effects of such potentially disruptive changes by containing them within local groups, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328972/presence-of-pgfplots-package-breaks-forest-environment-w-folder-option-en) shows that this is not always the case.

How, then, can `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}` be used to reverse a global invocation of `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}`?

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: IMHO, this is a bug! Extract from pgfmanual: _Use  `fpu=false` to deactivate the FPU. This will restore any change. Please note that this is not necessary if the FPU is used inside of a TEX group -- it will be deactivated afterwards anyway._

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, that's what I was wondering because that's how I understood the manual, too.

Comment: For the record: I agree that this is a bug which was reported to the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/129/) and solved in v1.15. So if you have this version and load it as well then your MWE works as expected. I assume, that this bug is also fixed in TikZ, but there we have to wait until the next release, too ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least for this case (`Mod` as well as `frac`, `random`, `setseed`, and `real`), Ti*k*Z does backup the function. This can be seen in `pgflibraryfpu.code.tex` line 169-172:

```
\def\pgfmathfloat@install@unimplemented#1{%
    \expandafter\pgfmathfloat@prepareuninstallcmd\csname pgfmath@#1@\endcsname%
    \expandafter\def\csname pgfmath#1@\endcsname##1{\pgfmathfloat@notimplemented{#1}}%
}
```

Here, `#1` is `Mod`. The first line backups the function of `Mod`. The second line redefines `Mod` to show the error message you saw.

However one can easily see an inconsistency that one macro is `\pgfmath@Mod@` and the other is `\pgfmathMod@`. It turns out that the later is the correct name of the function. So what is backuped and restored is an empty macro.

## TL;DR,

the correct definition is

```
\def\pgfmathfloat@install@unimplemented#1{%
    \expandafter\pgfmathfloat@prepareuninstallcmd\csname pgfmath#1@\endcsname%
    \expandafter\def\csname pgfmath#1@\endcsname##1{\pgfmathfloat@notimplemented{#1}}%
}
```

Copy and paste this between `\usetikzlibrary{fpu}` and `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}` will solve this problem.

---

Here is some test code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\ttfamily

\def\pgfmathfloat@install@unimplemented#1{%
    \expandafter\pgfmathfloat@prepareuninstallcmd\csname pgfmath#1@\endcsname%
    \expandafter\def\csname pgfmath#1@\endcsname##1{\pgfmathfloat@notimplemented{#1}}%
}


\def\pgfmathfloat@prepareuninstallcmd#1{%
    % and store backup information (globally - I don't want to do that
    % all the time when the FPU is used!):
    \message{^^J^^J backuping \string#1^^J\meaning#1}
    \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname pgfmathfloat@backup@\string#1\endcsname=#1%
    \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\pgfmathfloat@uninstall\expandafter{\pgfmathfloat@uninstall
        \expandafter\let\expandafter#1\csname pgfmathfloat@backup@\string#1\endcsname%
    }%
}

---

Mod@: \meaning\pgfmathMod@

--- Turn on \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}

Mod@:\meaning\pgfmathMod@

backup @Mod: \expandafter\meaning\csname pgfmathfloat@backup@\string\pgfmathMod@\endcsname

-- Turn off \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}

Mod@:\meaning\pgfmathMod@

\pgfmathsetmacro\myresult{Mod(-100,30)}
\tikz{\node[draw]{\myresult};}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So definitely a bug, then? Thanks for hunting ....

Comment: @cfr Perhaps I was not clear. The code under **TL;DR** is the correct definition. Paste it between `\usetikzlibrary{fpu}` and  `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}` will make your code compilable.

Comment: I understand that. But that is surely a bug.

Comment: @cfr well... the manual (p27) says something about bug report and [this links](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/) is somewhere bugs goes. But you probably already know that. So I am a little bit confused :(

Comment: Look at your linked question for Christian's answer

Comment: Thanks, but I can indeed (usually) figure out where to file bugs, as you say. I'm also rather confused. I really didn't think I was disagreeing with anything. And I really wasn't asking where to file bugs. Actually, I really was not intending to ask anything at all, so I'm altogether confused by people's trying to answer. Sorry if I created confusion by seeming to ask something. That really wasn't my intention.

Comment: `So definitely a bug, then? Thanks for hunting ....` is like `Monday tomorrow, then? Back to the grindstone ....`