# pgfplots seems to break tikz: "operation 'div' has not yet been implemented"

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've run into a problem where the usage of `pgfplots` seems to break `tikz`.  A MWE is below.  I get the error message that `div` is not yet implemented which is certainly not true.  If I comment out the line I marked, everything is fine.

This is on MiKTeX 2.9 with all packages updated.

I've found [this old article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328972/presence-of-pgfplots-package-breaks-forest-environment-w-folder-option-en/329015) and [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328996/how-can-the-effects-of-pgfkeys-pgf-fpu-true-be-reversed/331803#331803) which both seem to deal with the same problem, but I couldn't figure out how to adapt the solutions shown there to my problem.  I'n not (at least not explicitly) using the FPU library anywhere, am I?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}  % <- here's the culprit

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.8, yscale=-0.8]
  \foreach \n in {2, ..., 118} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{mod(int(\n - 2),13)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{div(int(\n - 2),13)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{ifthenelse(isprime(\n),10,0)}
    \fill[black!\c!white] (\x,\y) rectangle +(.85cm,.6cm);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it reported a bug which is solved in PGFPlots v1.15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based upon this Q&A: [Presence of 'pgfplots' package breaks 'forest' environment w/ 'folder' option enabled (due to FPU)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328972/presence-of-pgfplots-package-breaks-forest-environment-w-folder-option-en/329015) I get the following solution:

Replace

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
```

with

```
\makeatletter
\let\pgfmathdivX=\pgfmathdiv@
\let\pgfmathisprimeX=\pgfmathisprime@
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\let\pgfmathdiv@=\pgfmathdivX 
\let\pgfmathisprime@=\pgfmathisprimeX 
\makeatother
```

Actually, the `div` part can be omitted if the expression is written as `int(\n - 2)/13` rather than `div(int(\n - 2),13)`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\let\pgfmathisprimeX=\pgfmathisprime@
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\let\pgfmathisprime@=\pgfmathisprimeX 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=.8, yscale=-0.8]
  \foreach \n in {2, ..., 118} {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{mod(int(\n - 2),13)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{int(\n - 2)/13}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\c}{ifthenelse(isprime(\n),10,0)}
    \fill[black!\c!white] (\x,\y) rectangle +(.85cm,.6cm);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick (albeit it feels a bit clumsy).  What not works is replacing `div` with `/` as that would be `divide`.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I forgot that.