# `pgfmath` and `pgfplots` are clashing

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

`myRandomInteger` works fine under package `pgfmath`. If package `pgfplots` is also loaded compilation error `!Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, the operation 'random' has not yet been implemented in the floating point unit (in 'random(1,10000)'). ...` occurs. I would like to use the `random` functions of `pgfmath` with `pgfplots` also available. Any luck there?

```
\documentclass{article}
%  RN. 23 November 2016
%  DESCRIPTION: clash of pgfmath and pgfplots packages.
\usepackage{xparse} 
\usepackage{pgfmath}
%\usepackage{pgfplots} 
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \rn_RandomInteger:nn #1#2
  {
    \pgfmathparse{random(#1,#2)}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\myRandomInteger{O{1}O{100}}
  {
    \rn_RandomInteger:nn {#1}{#2}
    \pgfmathresult
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
    \myRandomInteger,
    \myRandomInteger, 
    \myRandomInteger

    \myRandomInteger[1][10000],
    \myRandomInteger[1][10000],
    \myRandomInteger[1][10000]

    \myRandomInteger[1][5],
    \myRandomInteger[1][5],
    \myRandomInteger[1][5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to a bug in the `fpu` library as explained in [Christian Feuersänger's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330076/). Modifying the workaround supplied there for the function you require, we can write the following to get things working.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
% adapted from ateb Christian Feuersänger: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330076/
\makeatletter
\let\pgfmathrandomX=\pgfmathrandom@
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\let\pgfmathrandom@=\pgfmathrandomX
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \rn_RandomInteger:nn #1#2
  {
    \pgfmathparse{random(#1,#2)}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\myRandomInteger{O{1}O{100}}
  {
    \rn_RandomInteger:nn {#1}{#2}
    \pgfmathresult
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
    \myRandomInteger,
    \myRandomInteger,
    \myRandomInteger

    \myRandomInteger[1][10000],
    \myRandomInteger[1][10000],
    \myRandomInteger[1][10000]

    \myRandomInteger[1][5],
    \myRandomInteger[1][5],
    \myRandomInteger[1][5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Problem solved, thanks! I normally keep all my `\usepackage` statements in an `.sty` file for better housekeeping, but know from experience that `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` constructs cause trouble in `.sty` files, so I better keep this in the preamble of my documents if required. Do you have a view on this?

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth If you put the code in a `.sty`, just remove `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. They are only needed because the category code of `@` is different in a document than in `.cls` and `.sty` files. If you are in a `.cls` or `.sty` file, then the code is already correct.