# Incompatibility of some macro arguments in package `tkz-base` with package `pgfplots'

Tags: pgfplots, tkz-base

I am a happy user of Alan Matthes' packages, most of the time. Just noted that certain arguments in his `tkz-base` package raise a `!Package PGF Math Error: Sorry, the operation 'gcd' has not been implemented in the floating point unit.` if package `pgfplots` is loaded, which I can't do without. In the MWE below 1. works fine, 2., 3. and 4. raise the error. Any thoughts there, anyone?

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 2 October 2107
%=======================
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%-----------------------
\begin{document}
1.\\    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmax=8,ymax=6]
\tkzGrid
\tkzAxeXY
\draw(-1,0)--(6,7);
\end{tikzpicture}
%\begin{comment}
2.\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmax=3,xstep=0.33333]
\tkzDrawX[label=$t$,text=blue,color=red]
\tkzLabelX[frac=3,text=blue,below = 9pt]
\end{tikzpicture}
3.\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=7,ymin=-1,ymax=1]
\tkzDrawX[trig=2]
\tkzLabelX[trig=2]
\end{tikzpicture}
4.\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmin=0,xmax=7,ymin=-1,ymax=1]
\tkzDrawX[trig=2]
\tkzLabelX[trig=2,below=8pt]
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is a known issue. see Christian's answer here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/330076/3235

Comment: ... and the answer is: add
    \makeatletter
    \let\pgfmathgcdX=\pgfmathgcd@
    \usepackage{pgfplots}%
    \let\pgfmathgcd@=\pgfmathgcdX
    \makeatother
to the preamble. Much obliged!

Comment: @percusse My comment was meant to be 5 lines of code, but did not turn out looking like that. Anyway, your comment led me to the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Do you mind if we close it as a duplicate ? Note that this is fixed in version 1.15

Comment: No I don't mind. Not sure what to make of your comment re Version 1.15. I would have hoped that MikTeX 2.9 supplies me with the latest version.

Comment: If you look at the start menu you'll see something called `Update (Admin)`, you can use that to update packages.

Comment: Done. All good!