# how to draw a sine waves

Tags: draw

I would draw more sine waves where wave parameter (top, bottom interval between two waves) depends from a value inserted on a \foreach (or similar) value.

Can someone give me example?

Renato

ok, maybe the cycle is too much.
Ho can I Dra one single sine wave ?

Comment: I guess you should first add a code with the foreach loop and then someone will for sure add the sine.

Comment: I still have no code! I have just an Idea...

Comment: Here is a way to loop over sine waves. `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:360,smooth] ({\x/100},{0.5*\X*sin(\x)});}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` My hope is that you can use this as a basis for a question.

Comment: The answers here show how to draw a sine wave: [Axis with trigonometric labels in PGFPlots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34939/4301).

Comment: because, I don't know how to do that

Comment: Just click on the check mark left of the answer that you find most useful. You can only accept one answer per question. If you want to loop over plots in pgfplots, as suggested by @PeterGrill, you probably need to use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`.

Comment: Hi marmot. I've finaly accepted all my answer. I would accept also the one you gave me. Is it possible also if it is a comment?