# Errors loading siunitx package with pgfplots and custom code I've included some code that seems incompatible with `\siunitx`. How can I fix it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, siunitx

I found some code from [Axis with trigonometric labels in PGFPlots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34939/axis-with-trigonometric-labels-in-pgfplots)

to use multiples of `\pi` in trig graphing but it causes an error if I also load `\siunitx` which I also would like to have.

The errors that are listed include:

> xparse function not expandable
>
> Package \siunitx error  Invalid numerical input
>
> Package tikz math library error: Unknown function or keyword `\num`
> error

Can someone help me reconcile the two? I would like the capability the code offers but also keep the functionality of `\siunitx`.  I would like someone to help me fix the error and give a simple explanation of my error.

````
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,hypcap=false]{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.16}
%\usepackage{siunitx}   %%%%if this is loaded, it causes an error. 

\pgfplotsset{
    % Typeset fractions of pi at regular intervals on x axis
    x axis in pi/.style={
        % Make sure the x axis is in radians
        trig format plots=rad,
        % Set tick distance from style argument
        xtick distance={pi/#1},
        % Set label style: calculate reduced fraction of pi
        xticklabel={
            \tikzmath{
                % Calculate this tick's multiple of pi/#1
                int \numorig, \gcd, \number, \denom, \absnum;
                \numorig = round(\tick*#1/pi);
                % Calculate reduced fraction for \numorig/#1
                \gcd = gcd(\numorig,#1);
                \number = \numorig / \gcd;
                \absnum = abs(\number);
                \denom = #1 / \gcd;
                % Build label text
                if \number < 0 then {
                    let \sign = -;
                } else {
                    let \sign =;
                };
                if \absnum == 1 then {
                    let \numpi = \pi;
                } else {
                    let \numpi = \absnum\pi;
                };
                if \denom == 1 then {
                    if \number == 0 then {
                        { \strut$0$ };
                    } else {
                        { \strut$\sign\numpi$ };
                    };
                } else {
                    { \strut$\sign\frac{\numpi}{\denom}$ };
                    % Other style with all pi symbols same and aligned:
                    %{ \strut$\sign\frac{\absnum}{\denom}\pi$ };
                };
            }
        },
    },
}

\printanswers
\graphicspath{ {./dir1/} }
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=14cm,
        axis equal image,
        domain=-2*pi:2*pi,
        axis lines=center,
        enlargelimits={abs=0.4},
        no markers,
        samples=100,
        ytick distance = 1,
        x axis in pi=2, % tick distance as fraction of pi
        ]
        \addplot {sin(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

```
````

Please help.  In summary, explain the error and describe how I can fix it (i.e. keeping `\siunitx` and the code.

Here is the full copy of the errors that I get using Overleaf:

> ```
> Compile Error. Sorry, your LaTeX code couldn't compile for some reason.
> Please check the errors below for details, or view the raw log.
>  test.tex, line 85
> Missing \endcsname inserted.
>
> <to be read again> 
>                    \xparse function is not expandable 
> l.85     \end{axis}
>                    
> The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
> not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
>
>  test.tex, line 85
> Package siunitx Error: Invalid numerical input '='.
>
> For immediate help type H <return>.
>  ...                                              
>                                                   
> l.85     \end{axis}
>
>  test.tex, line 85
> Extra \endcsname.
>
> \tikz@math@next ...math@parsed@keyword \endcsname 
>                                                   \relax \expandafter \ifx \...
> l.85     \end{axis}
>                    
> I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.
>
>  test.tex, line 85
> Extra \endcsname.
>
> \tikz@math@next ...math@parsed@keyword \endcsname 
>                                                   \relax \tikz@math@error {U...
> l.85     \end{axis}
>                    
> I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.
>
>  test.tex, line 85
> Package tikz Error: tikz math library: Unknown function or keyword '\num ='.
>
> See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...                                              
>                                                   
> l.85     \end{axis}
>                    
> This error message was generated by an \errmessage
> command, so I can't give any explicit help.
> Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
> and deduce the truth by order and method.
>
>  test.tex, line 85
> Package tikz Error: tikz math library: Unknown function or keyword '\num ='.
>
> See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
> Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
>  ...                                              
>                                                   
> l.85     \end{axis}
>                    
> (That was another \errmessage.)
>
>  test.tex, line 85
> Package siunitx Error: Invalid numerical input '='.
>
> For immediate help type H <return>.
>  ...                                              
>                                                   
> l.85     \end{axis}
>                    
> (That makes 100 errors; please try again.) 
> Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
>  37290 strings out of 480906
>  871318 string characters out of 5908280
>  1235087 words of memory out of 5000000
>  52330 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
>  541835 words of font info for 55 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
>  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
>  73i,5n,127p,1576b,2023s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
>
>  test.tex
> ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
> ```

Comment: Num is an siunitx macro as well so using it as a variable is probably not a good idea. Often a good idea to prefix your personal macro names when in dought

Comment: yes.  I noticed that too.  I changed all the code to `\numb` but it still gave errors.

Comment: Then please cite the full log on this example not just this error, there might be more relevant info in the log

Comment: I'm not sure if I did it correctly but I copied and pasted the errors I saw.

Comment: The reason for wanting the entire log is that we can also see other information, for example if your setup is very old, so please replace this with the entire log

Comment: Also you're still using `\num ` as a variable in your example

Comment: I'm using Overleaf and I"m not sure how to obtain the entire log.  I've changed `\num` to `\number`

Comment: Make your variable names more personal/unique `\number` is also not a good name. I used `\numberX` and the example compiles just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here seems to be using already defined macros as internal variables. TikZ/pgf sometimes have a tendency to make these variables **global** and thus this creates problem later on.

In this case `\num` comes from `siunitx` and is expected to behave in a certain way.

Using `\number` is not a good idea either as this is an important Plain TeX macro.

For scratch variables like this is is often better to use `\myNumA`, `\myNumB` etc to ensure that these are not already in use.