# Labeling axis in π increments

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, axis

i would like to lable my x-axis on a tikz-picture in π/4 increments, like in the wikipedia sin and cos graphic [1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinus_und_Kosinus#/media/Datei:Sine_cosine_one_period.svg). This is my code (but it doesnt work):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Schriftart
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Umlaute im Quellcode benutzen
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Umlaute korrekt darstellen
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Worttrennung
\usepackage[landscape, margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0mm}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, domain=0:{2*pi}]
        %\clip (-0.1,-0.2) rectangle (1.1,0.75); %Bildausschnitt
        \draw[step=0.5,gray,very thin] (0,-1.4) grid (6.4,1.4); %Hintergrundgitter
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (6.5,0) node[right]{$x$}; %x-Achse
        \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[above]{$y$}; %y-Achse

        \foreach \x in {0\pi,0.5\pi,...\pi,2\pi}{$\x$}
            \draw (\x,2pt) -- (\x,-2pt) node[below]{$\x$};

        \foreach \y in {-1,-0.5, ...,1} 
            \draw(2pt,\y) -- (-2pt,\y) node[left]{$\y$};

        \draw[color=red, very thick, smooth] plot (\x,{sin(\x r)});
        \draw[color=blue, very thick, smooth] plot (\x,{cos(\x r)});
        %\draw[smooth, variable=\x, blue] (0.0) plot ({\x}, {sin(\x r)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). For graphs I would highly recommend you use `pgfplots` (which uses `tikz`)  as that is specfically designed for graphing. An example that may help you get strted is [Axis with trigonometric labels in PGFPlots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34939/4301).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really want to stick with `tikz` (although I would recommend you use `pgfplots` for graphing),you can:

1. Use `\pgfmathsetmacro` to compute the appropriate x-axis location as a multiple of `pi`.
2. Use `\pgfmathprintnumber` to format the number with the number format set to `frac`.
3. Detect the case of `1` (so you don't end up with a label of `1\pi`).

#### Notes:

- `\pi` is not a number. It is used to typeset the greek letter pi.
- One example of how to use `pgfplots` is availalbe at [Axis with trigonometric labels in PGFPlots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34939/4301).

#### References:

- If you are creating several graphs, I would recommend to switch to using the `axis` environment from the `pgfplots` package which is specifically designed for graphs.  An example of its use with trigonometric graphs is at [Axis with trigonometric labels in PGFPlots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34939/4301).

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}% needed for for the 'frac' detection

\NewDocumentCommand{\FormatMultipleOfGivenValue}{s O{} m}{%
    %% #1 = * to suppress the display of "0"
    %% #2 = multiplier to display
    %% #3 = real number
    \pgfmathifisint{#3}{%
        \pgfmathparse{int(#3)}%
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0
            \IfBooleanF{#1}{0}% Suppress "0" if * option provided.
        \else
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1\relax
                %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068
                \ifx#2\pi\relax\pi\else1\fi
            \else
                \pgfmathresult#2
            \fi
        \fi
    }{%
        \pgfmathprintnumber{#3}#2
    }%
}%
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, domain=0:{2*pi}]
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, frac, frac whole=false}
        \draw [xstep=0.25*pi, ystep=0.5, gray,very thin] (0,-1.0) grid (2*pi,1.0);
        \draw [-latex] (0,0)    -- (6.5,0) node [right] {$x$}; %x-Achse
        \draw [-latex] (0,-1.3) -- (0,1.3) node [above] {$y$}; %y-Achse

        \foreach \x in {0.0, 0.5,..., 2, 6.5}{
            \pgfmathsetmacro\xCoord{\x*pi}
            \draw (\xCoord,2pt) -- (\xCoord,-2pt) node [below] 
                {$\FormatMultipleOfGivenValue*[\pi]{\x}$};
        }

        \foreach \y in {-1,-0.5, ...,1} {
            \draw (2pt,\y) -- (-2pt,\y) node [left] {$\FormatMultipleOfGivenValue{\y}$};
        }
        
        \draw[color=red,  ultra thick, smooth] plot (\x,{sin(\x r)});
        \draw[color=blue, ultra thick, smooth] plot (\x,{cos(\x r)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello Peter, thank you very much for your help witch my first question on stackexchange! Your solution seems easy and reasonable, i will implement it!

Comment: @infinitezero: Thanks for catching that -- has been corrected.

Answer (score 8):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[margin=.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=1.5]
        % first option for a grid like a millimetral grahic paper (next 3 lines)
        \draw[thin,brown!25] (-.5,-1.5) grid[step= 1mm] ++ (7.5,3);
        \draw[semithick,brown!50]   (-.5,-1.5) grid[step= 5mm] ++  (7.5,3);
        \draw[    thick,brown!75]   (-.5,-1.5) grid[step=10mm] ++  (7.5,3);
        
        % second option for a grid in dotted gray in next line (uncomment the next line but comment the preceding 3 lines)
        %\draw[dotted] (-0,-1) grid (6.5,1);
        
        % x axis and its label
        \draw[->] (-.5,0) -- (6.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
        
        % x axis graduations in integers 
        \foreach \x in {1,2,...,6}
        \fill[shift={(\x,0)}] circle(.5pt) node[above] {\tiny $\x$};
        
        % x axis graduations in \pi
        \foreach \x /\n in {.7854/$\frac{\pi}{4}$,1.5708/$\frac{\pi}{2}$,2.3562/$\frac34\pi$,3.1416/$\pi$,3.9270/$\frac54\pi$,4.7124/$\frac32\pi$,5.4978/$\frac74\pi$,6.2832/$2\pi$} \draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\tiny \n};
        
        % y axis, its label and graduations
        \draw[->] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5) node[below right] {$y$};
        \foreach \y in {-1,1}
        \draw[shift={(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\tiny $\y$};
        \node[below left] at (0,0) {\tiny $0$};
        
        % draw functions
        \draw[smooth,blue,mark=none,domain=0:6.283,line width=1.5pt] plot (\x,{sin(deg(\x))});
        \draw[smooth,magenta,mark=none,domain=-0:6.283,line width=1.5pt] plot (\x,{cos(deg(\x))});
        
        % draw the functions names
        \draw[] (2,-1) node[magenta,below](1) {$y=\cos x$};
        \draw[] (2,1) node[blue,above](1) {$y=\sin x$};
        
        % plot the intersections points A and B
        \fill[black,shift={(3.9270,-.707)}] circle(1.5pt) node[below] {\tiny B};
        \fill[black,shift={(.7854,.707)}] circle(1.5pt) node[above] {\tiny A};
        
        % draw the exact coordinates of A and B
        \draw[] (5,-.95) node[below] (3) {\tiny A$\left(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\right)$ \quad \tiny B$\left(\frac{5}{4}\pi,-\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\right)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Yet another way using the tikz library `datavisualization.formats.functions`

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {datavisualization.formats.functions}
    
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[]
\datavisualization [school book axes,
visualize as smooth line/.list={sin,cos},
sin={style={red,very thick}, label in legend={text=$\sin(x)$}},
cos={style={blue,very thick},label in legend={text=$\cos(x)$}},
all axes={ticks={step=0.5}},
x axis={grid={step=0.25},
        length=13cm,
        ticks={tick unit=\pi},
        label=$x$,
        max value=2.25},
y axis={grid,length=6cm,label=$y$,max value=1.25}
]
data [set=sin,format=function] {
var x : interval [0:2];
func y = sin(\value x * pi r);
}
data [set=cos,format=function] {
var x : interval [0:2];
func y = cos(\value x * pi r);
};
\end{tikzpicture}
       
       
\end{document}
```

[image]