# beamer and pgfplots doesn't work if tikz 'math' library is used

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots

The code provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/396298/18401) (where the workaround for `gcd()` issue isn't needed anymore, at least in `pgfplots` 1.18) does:

- work if the class used is e.g. `article`,
- not work if the class used is `beamer`.

Indeed, the compilation of the following MCE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

% Load math library, for \tikzmath
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\pgfplotsset{
  % Typeset fractions of pi at regular intervals on x axis
  x axis in pi/.style={
    % Make sure the x axis is in radians
    trig format plots=rad,
    % Set tick distance from style argument
    xtick distance={pi/#1},
    % Set label style: calculate reduced fraction of pi
    xticklabel={
      \tikzmath{
        % Calculate this tick's multiple of pi/#1
        int \numorig, \gcd, \num, \denom, \absnum;
        \numorig = round(\tick*#1/pi);
        % Calculate reduced fraction for \numorig/#1
        \gcd = gcd(\numorig,#1);
        \num = \numorig / \gcd;
        \absnum = abs(\num);
        \denom = #1 / \gcd;
        % Build label text
        if \num < 0 then {
          let \sign = -;
        } else {
          let \sign =;
        };
        if \absnum == 1 then {
          let \numpi = \pi;
        } else {
          let \numpi = \absnum\pi;
        };
        if \denom == 1 then {
          if \num == 0 then {
            { \strut$0$ };
          } else {
            { \strut$\sign\numpi$ };
          };
        } else {
          { \strut$\sign\frac{\numpi}{\denom}$ };
          % Other style with all pi symbols same and aligned:
          % { \strut$\sign\frac{\absnum}{\denom}\pi$ };
        };
      }
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      x axis in pi=2, % tick distance as fraction of pi
      ]
      \addplot {sin(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

fails with the error:

```
(./test-beamer.nav)
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.62 \end{frame}
                
?
```

Note that adding the `fragile` option to the `frame` environment doesn't help.

Do you understand what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue lies in the way the `math` library handles variable names; in essence for the `\gcd`-variable it'll try to use it inside of a `\csname` construct.

Your issue can be reduced to the following MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{\gcd = 1;}
\stop
```

The difference lies in LaTeX's standard definition of `\gcd` (`\meaning` starts with `macro`) and the definition in `amsmath` (`\meaning` starts with `\protected`), so we can further reduce our MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
% make \gcd \protected, but don't alter it otherwise
\protected\expandafter\def\expandafter\gcd\expandafter{\gcd}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{\gcd = 1;}
\stop
```

Now the `math`-parser doesn't understand that this is a variable but thinks it's part of a keyword, grabs everything up to the next space (or does it? Not sure here), and tries to build the keyword name of that with `\csname` which fails badly.

So you can't assign to variables which are already defined `\protected` in the `math` library (well, if you use the `let` keyword you can, so `\tikzmath{let \gcd=;}` works and afterwards you can use the name `\gcd`)!

If you change that variable's name (e.g., to `\mygcd`) everything works again:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

% Load math library, for \tikzmath
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\pgfplotsset{
  % Typeset fractions of pi at regular intervals on x axis
  x axis in pi/.style={
    % Make sure the x axis is in radians
    trig format plots=rad,
    % Set tick distance from style argument
    xtick distance={pi/#1},
    % Set label style: calculate reduced fraction of pi
    xticklabel={
      \tikzmath{
        % Calculate this tick's multiple of pi/#1
        int \numorig, \gcd, \num, \denom, \absnum;
        \numorig = round(\tick*#1/pi);
        % Calculate reduced fraction for \numorig/#1
        \mygcd = gcd(\numorig,#1);
        \num = \numorig / \mygcd;
        \absnum = abs(\num);
        \denom = #1 / \mygcd;
        % Build label text
        if \num < 0 then {
          let \sign = -;
        } else {
          let \sign =;
        };
        if \absnum == 1 then {
          let \numpi = \pi;
        } else {
          let \numpi = \absnum\pi;
        };
        if \denom == 1 then {
          if \num == 0 then {
            { \strut$0$ };
          } else {
            { \strut$\sign\numpi$ };
          };
        } else {
          { \strut$\sign\frac{\numpi}{\denom}$ };
          % Other style with all pi symbols same and aligned:
          % { \strut$\sign\frac{\absnum}{\denom}\pi$ };
        };
      }
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      x axis in pi=2, % tick distance as fraction of pi
      ]
      \addplot {sin(x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What a strange incompatibility! :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé found the real culprit, will update.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé edited the answer, it's still not absolutely in depth, but the important bits are explained, I think.