# PGFPlots how to add a label "0" to the origin

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using pgfplots to plot the a function. I have been looking around on the forums, but I could  not find a solution. I would like to origin to be indicated as a 0 on the x axis. 
I would also like to get the axis labels to appear respectively left and below the axis. Any ideas?

I have the following plot:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=7cm, height=2cm,xmin=-6,xmax=6,ymin=0,ymax=1,
no markers,
samples=50,
axis lines=left, 
axis lines=middle, 
scale only axis,
% extra y ticks={0.5},
/pgfplots/ytick={0, 0.5,1}, % make steps of length 0.5
/pgfplots/xtick={-5,0,5}, % make steps of length 5
    xlabel=$Li$,
    ylabel={$f_{comp}(Li))$}
  ] 
    \addplot {1/(1+exp(-x)}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I expanded the code to a full working code example and added a picture of the output.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `middle` option for the axis lines assumes that the axis lines intersect, so the `0` ticks aren't shown. If you use `axis y line=middle, axis x line=bottom` instead of `axis lines=middle`, you get the desired tick mark:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    width=7cm, height=2cm,xmin=-6,xmax=6,ymin=0,ymax=1,
    no markers,
    samples=50,
    axis y line=middle, 
    axis x line=bottom,
    scale only axis,
    ytick={0, 0.5,1}, % make steps of length 0.5
    xtick={-5,0,5}, % make steps of length 5
    xlabel=$Li$,
    ylabel={$f_{comp}(Li))$}
  ] 
    \addplot {1/(1+exp(-x)}; 
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Combined withevery axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north west},
every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=north east},...  I got a perfect result!

Comment: What could I do, if I wanted to keep both axes as `middle` (so they intersect) _and_ print the zero labels on top of them? Would that be possible?

Comment: @sdaau: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39099/2552

Comment: Many, many thanks for that, @Jake - that answers it completely! Cheers!

Comment: What if the graph has negative y-values?

Comment: @theonlygusti: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39098/need-to-do-some-changes-to-pgfplots-axis