# Place tick at origin of pgfplots axis using axis lines center

Tags: pgfplots

Currently I have the figure as shown below (generated with the code below it) As you can see, the origin is not marked with 2 as I would expect based on the tick labels I explicitly set. Why does `pgfplots` do this and how can I put arbitrary text there?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style={-},
            xtick={-2,0,2},
            xticklabels={1,2,3},
            xmin=-3.5,
            xmax=3.5,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=5,
        ]
        \addplot+[ycomb, mark=none] table {
            -3 1
            -2 2
            -1 3
            0 4
            1 3
            2 2
            3 1
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace `axis lines=center` by `axis y line=middle, axis x line=bottom`.

Comment: @gernot I think this is not a duplicate, see Stefan's answer. pgfplots trying to avoid overdrawing over tick label

Comment: @percusse As I understand the other post, `pgfplots` thinks (because of `axis lines=center`) that the y axis extends below the x axis and therefore obscures the tick. In this case we now have two cures for the same disease, where `hide obscured x ticks=false` seems to cure only the symptom.

Comment: @gernot Ah yes, I read too fast. You are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the default setting of `hide obscured x ticks` which is `true`. Set it to `false` and you will get the desired result.

But the better solution is the one given by gernot in [his comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346851/place-tick-at-origin-of-pgfplots-axis-using-axis-lines-center#comment851417_346851) and as it has been voted for the [duplicate question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78763/pgfplots-how-to-add-a-label-0-to-the-origin).

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                axis lines=center,
                axis line style={-},
                xtick={-2,0,2},
                xticklabels={1,2,3},
                hide obscured x ticks=false,    % <-- added
                xmin=-3.5,
                xmax=3.5,
                ymin=0,
                ymax=5,
            ]
            \addplot+[ycomb, mark=none] table {
                -3 1
                -2 2
                -1 3
                0 4
                1 3
                2 2
                3 1
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]